# Using MvxLang attribute in searchable.xml and menu.xml

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm using the JSON localization plugin to add some string resource files to my xamarin.android project.  Is there support for the MvxLang attribute in non-layout files such as searchable.xml and menu.xml files?

For example, I'd like to replace the below @string references with MvxLang attributes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/ApplicationName"
    android:hint="@string/SearchHint"
    android:searchButtonText="@string/SearchHint">
</searchable>
```

Thanks
Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There's no built-in support for either of these.

For menu items, I'm sure you could add tokens to them fairly easily and then replace those tokens with strings when you load/inflate these files. Or alternatively you could even construct the menus in code.

For `searchable` I think the problem may be more difficult - I'm not sure that Android gives you much access to the searchable file or data object - I think the system uses them at a package level. I suspect for those few searchable text strings, you may have to use the built-in Android i18n system.